# Tkinter add icon to custom title-bar (overridden)

Tags: python, tkinter, customization, titlebar

I want to create a custom Title-bar. But I have a problem with the icon.
I want it to be left but instead it is just in the window...
[image]

I have my template from here: https://github.com/Terranova-Python/Tkinter-Menu-Bar/blob/main/main.py

The code I tried to add the image:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img  = Image.open("M.ico") 
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

close_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ×  ', command=root.destroy,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,font=("calibri", 13),bd=0,fg='white',highlightthickness=0)
expand_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ', command=maximize_me,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0,fg='white',font=("calibri", 13),highlightthickness=0)
minimize_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ',command=minimize_me,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0,fg='white',font=("calibri", 13),highlightthickness=0)
title_bar_image = Label(image=photo,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0)
title_bar_title = Label(title_bar, text=tk_title, bg=RGRAY,bd=0,fg='white',font=("helvetica", 10),highlightthickness=0)
```

I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking, you want to set the window icon, right?

Comment: Well normally it does look like this: [https://i.imgur.com/WfBmgDe.png](https://i.imgur.com/WfBmgDe.png) 
But I override the titlebar so I can create my own but I dont know how to get the image left to the title "App"

Comment: Is it because you need to parent (anchor) the image to title_bar?

Comment: Ups yes thank you xD 
    title_bar_image = Label(title_bar, image=photo, width=25, height=25, bg=RGRAY, bd=0)
fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an official answer, the problem was that `title_bar_image` was not anchored to `title_bar`. The revised code snippet is now

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img  = Image.open("M.ico") 
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

close_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ×  ', command=root.destroy,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,font=("calibri", 13),bd=0,fg='white',highlightthickness=0)
expand_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ', command=maximize_me,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0,fg='white',font=("calibri", 13),highlightthickness=0)
minimize_button = Button(title_bar, text='  ',command=minimize_me,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0,fg='white',font=("calibri", 13),highlightthickness=0)
title_bar_image = Label(title_bar, image=photo,bg=RGRAY,padx=2,pady=2,bd=0)
title_bar_title = Label(title_bar, text=tk_title, bg=RGRAY,bd=0,fg='white',font=("helvetica", 10),highlightthickness=0)
```